# I am having troubles converting a dataframe into a list

Tags: r

I have made the following dataframe (ampGenesTable) of amplified genes:

```
Gene   Description           Chr   Start       End
LYZ    lysozyme precursor    12    68028400    68034280
RB1    retinoblastoma 1      13    47775883    47954027
...    ...
```

I would like to add a sixth column called "Cytoband". To do so, I have another dataframe (amplification) that I want to convert into a list (there can be several genes per cytoband):

```
Gene1     Gene2    Gene3   Gene4    Cytoband 
ERLIN2                              8p12
ERBB2                               17q12
APOD      MUC20                     3q29
...
```

I created a list:

```
geneList <- split(amplification[,1:4], amplification$Cytoband)
```

The problem is that I can't search geneList. For example, if I type:

```
"ERLIN2" %in% geneList
```

I get FALSE. Upon closer examination, I realized that each element is a list:

```
...

$`9p23`
        X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16
9p23 PTPRD                                           

$`9q34.3`
             X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10 X11 X12 X13 X14 X15 X16
9q34.3 FLJ20433
```

How could I transform the list so each element is a simple character vector and make the search work? If it does, could I add the Cytoband column to ampGenesTable with:

```
ampGenesTable$Cytoband <- sapply(geneList, function(x){
       if (ampGenesTable$Gene %in% geneList[[x]]
       return x
   }
```

Any hint would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(ampGenesTable)){
  gene <- as.character(ampGenesTable[i,1])
  position <- grep(gene,geneList1)
  ampGenesTable[i,7] <- names(geneList1)[position]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn everything in your list into a character you could just run some apply functions.  If you save that list your check should work fine when you run `lapply` on that.

I'm not quite sure what you want to do if it is TRUE.?

This assumes that the blank cells have NA in them.

```
geneList1 <- lapply(geneList, function(x) sapply(x, as.character))
lapply(geneList1, function(x) "ERLIN2" %in% x)



#$`17q12`
#[1] FALSE
#
#$`3q29`
#[1] FALSE
#
#$`8p12`
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input!! Please see the edit: I managed to create a loop that solved the problem! :D